# convert how to Convert textbox to integer c#

Tags: c#

I'v problem
how to Convert textbox to float c#

I have in my textbox.text
example

8.1.1

I did this cod but error

//

```
         int a ;

         a = val (model.Text);

        //

        if (a >= 6)
        {

        }
```

Convert textbox to float

some one pleas help me

Comment: not eccapt erorr

Comment: Can you clarify your question, you your title and code say `int`, but the question body says `float`.  Which is it?   And if you are trying to convert the value 8.1.1 it's not going to work in either case because it's not a valid integer _or_ float value.  Please review [ask].

Answer (score -1):

in order to convert textbox text into a float you need to use float.Parse()

```
    float a;
    a = float.Parse(model.Text);
```